# Adding Iframe from module as portlet in liferay7

Tags: java, gradle, liferay, portlet, portal

I am new to liferay and using Liferay7. Now Instead of adding iframe manually in the portal i want to make a module and add it as a portlet and then want to make the iframe url dynamic so that i can change the url of the iframe based on some UI action in the portal. Any suggestions as to how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you aware, there's already liferay iframe portlet available.

> http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe%20Portlet

You can either customize it or write your custom iframe event portlet.

Custom iframe event portlet will listen to any events from other portlet and act accordingly. You can write event portlet using following link, check for Event Inter-portlet Communication

> https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication

From other portlet you can either trigger this event which will force iframe portlet to change url.